# Set a background image for a button in html and then change the images from javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to set a background image for a button through html by using the following line:

```
<button> id="Flower" type="button" src="Images/Roses"></button>
```

Then I would like to be able to change its image by clicking another button to store an image file in an array (the array is needed because I want to store multiple images in an array to change multiple button background images) in java script by creating a function:

```
let images = [ ]
function insert(images) {
     images.push(images)
     document.getElementByID("Flower).src = Images[0]
}
```

In HTML another button would have the function as the onlclick:

```
<button type="button" onclick="insert(Images/Tulips)"></button>
```

It seems like I cant use an image file location as a parameter in a function. Is that correct?

Comment: use `htmlElement.style.backgroundImage = "url('iimage.jpg')";` and take time to read docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/

Comment: I suggest you to go with Jquery for this.

Answer (score 0):

To change button Images dynamically on click from an array, find below a working example  as per your question this is a solution to handle a small array of images, just modify the code for where you need to set the path of the images name and this should get you started..

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <style>
        #Flower{
            /* use the css to fix the background size as per the button size */
            background-size: 100px 100px;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }
        </style>
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
<!-- your button with the size as set in the css, if you need to change it make sure you change in both html style and css-->
        <button id="Flower" type="button" style="width:100px; height:100px"></button>
    <button id="changeImg" onclick="insert(); return false;">Change Image</button>

    <script>

    let images = [
//change the images names as per your images location
        {'name':'image1'},
        {'name':'image2'},
        {'name':'iamge3'},
        ]
    i = 0
    let myButton = document.getElementById("Flower")
    function insert() {
        if(i == 0){
            myButton.style.backgroundImage = 'url('+ images[0].name +')'
            i++
        }else if(i==1){
            myButton.style.backgroundImage = 'url('+ images[1].name +')'
            i++
        }else if(i==2){
            myButton.style.backgroundImage = 'url('+ images[2].name +')'
            i=0
        }
    }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```